# Datetime value being converted when parsed from MySQL

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I have a problem here. I have a MySQL database with datetime field which has format: '2016-12-31 21:59:59'. I am fetching this value in nodejs and pass it to the table, but in table it has format: Sat Dec 31 2016 21:59:59 GMT+0200 (EET) why does this happen and how I can make it so it is
'2017-01-01 23:59:59' in the table too?

This is how I fetch it:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM TestInformation", function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Bad query!');
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Successful query!');
        //console.log(rows);
        information = rows;
        res.render('index', {information: information});
    }
});
```

And this is how I use it:

```
<input type="text" id="last_measure" placeholder="Last Measure"          name="last_measure"
               class="form-control" value="{{information.0.Last_Measure}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the query like the following:

```
"SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as dateColumn FROM TestInformation"
```

Using the above query, you can change the date format of the `dateColumn` to represent in console.

I should have mentioned that, this format is the default format of storing Timestamp in MySQL, and what you see is the format of representation in your application.

Comment: Depending on the size of your sql selection, mysql is awfully slow with string manipulation but this will work. You can also use new Date() and toLocaleString(); based on the linux date format of mysql.